# PHP: How to check the season of the year and set a class accordingly

Tags: php

I have a website which uses 4 different background images for the header area which visually corresponds to the season of the ear (summer, autumn etc.) – for the summer timeframe I use one image, for the autumn – another one and so on. The problem is that I have to manually change those images once the season of the year changes.

Maybe someone could show how would it be possible to check the current time / season of the year and then print the corresponding classes to the header element (.summer, .autumn etc.)?

I assume using PHP would be the way.

Comment: Are you talking about meteorological seasons, or astronomical seasons?

Comment: Could be done with a simple switch statement or if/elseif block - just test whether today's date is between certain dates that you define as the beginning of your seasons, and set the image path accordingly

Comment: @MarkBaker astronomical (summer, autumn, winter, sprint)

Comment: @EatPeanutButter Yes, that would work, the problem is I don't know the PHP...

Comment: @Daniel If you're developing websites, this is probably a good skill to learn. Plenty of tutorials online; check them out, give it a try, and then come back here when you get stuck or have a specific question.

Comment: So if it's astronomical, you need to check date ranges; if it were meteorological, you'd only need to check months

Comment: @EatPeanutButter Yes, I know. But I'm actually a designer of UI/UX and then a front-end (HTML, CSS, JS) coder. And the knowledge of PHP is very basic as I use it just for the theming of a Drupal based websites... :(

Comment: @MarkBaker Then the meteorological would work as well.

Comment: Interesting question / challenge. The [dates of seasons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Season) are always changing and different depending what part of the world you live in. Then you have to take your server time vs the visiting users local time into question.

Comment: @mistermartin Well it would be enough to check it only by months and only in relation to my server, as it is a website of a local nature... Could you help me?

Comment: @Daniel sure, give me a few to come up with something.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As I stated in the comments, this is an interesting challenge because the [dates of seasons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Season) are always changing and different depending what part of the world you live in. Your server time and the website visitor's local time are also a factor.

Since you've stated you're just interested in a simple example based on server time and you're not concerned with it being exact, this should get you rolling:

```
// get today's date
$today = new DateTime();
echo 'Today is: ' . $today->format('m-d-Y') . '<br />';

// get the season dates
$spring = new DateTime('March 20');
$summer = new DateTime('June 20');
$fall = new DateTime('September 22');
$winter = new DateTime('December 21');

switch(true) {
    case $today >= $spring && $today < $summer:
        echo 'It\'s Spring!';
        break;

    case $today >= $summer && $today < $fall:
        echo 'It\'s Summer!';
        break;

    case $today >= $fall && $today < $winter:
        echo 'It\'s Fall!';
        break;

    default:
        echo 'It must be Winter!';
}
```

This will output:

```
Today is: 11-30-2016
It's Fall!
```

Comment: Object of class DateTime could not be converted to int

Answer (score 5):

One might consider this necromancy, Yet when I was looking for ready to use method that does this I've got here.
Mister Martin answer was good assuming the year will not changes, here is my snippet, might be useful for someone in future:

```
private function timestampToSeason(\DateTime $dateTime): string{
    $dayOfTheYear = $dateTime->format('z');
    if($dayOfTheYear < 80 || $dayOfTheYear > 356){
        return 'Winter';
    }
    if($dayOfTheYear < 173){
        return 'Spring';
    }
    if($dayOfTheYear < 266){
        return 'Summer';
    }
    return 'Fall';
}
```

cheers!

Comment: it's wrong, we are in spring, and the day of year is 79 not 80, it depend of the year

Comment: I like the simplicity of the method.  But please edit to stress that you are using astronomical seasons here. Note that the Equinoxes and Solstices do not fall on consistent dates from year to year.

Comment: meh, Progrock and neoteknic both of You are right, it was meant to be simple snipet, I'll update it in a free time, so that it would include leap year, and other stuff

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is quite old, but none of the answers on this or any of the other questions that ask this question account for timezones, hemispheres, and different calendars in the same function, and since this came up first when I Googled for this, here's what I ended up writing myself.

If you want to get fancier you could calculate the actual Astronomical dates, geolocate the user, internationalize the season name output, etc., but that's beyond the scope of this question anyway.

```
function get_season( string $date = '', string $timezone = 'Europe/London', string $hemisphere = 'northern', string $calendar = 'meteorological' ): string {

    // Create the calendars that you want to use for each hemisphere.
    $seasons = array(
        'northern' => array(
            'astronomical'   => array(
                'spring' => '03-20', // mm-dd
                'summer' => '06-21',
                'autumn' => '09-22',
                'winter' => '12-21',
            ),
            'meteorological' => array(
                'spring' => '03-01',
                'summer' => '06-01',
                'autumn' => '09-01',
                'winter' => '12-01',
            ),
        ),
        'southern' => array(
            'astronomical'   => array(
                'spring' => '09-22',
                'summer' => '12-21',
                'autumn' => '03-20',
                'winter' => '06-21',
            ),
            'meteorological' => array(
                'spring' => '09-01',
                'summer' => '12-01',
                'autumn' => '03-01',
                'winter' => '06-01',
            ),
        ),
    );

    // Set $date to today if no date specified.
    if ( empty( $date ) ) {
        $date = new \DateTimeImmutable( 'now', new \DateTimeZone( $timezone ) );
    } else {
        $date = new \DateTimeImmutable( $date, new \DateTimeZone( $timezone ) );
    }

    // Set the relevant defaults.
    $seasons        = $seasons[ strtolower( $hemisphere ) ][ strtolower( $calendar ) ];
    $current_season = array_key_last( $seasons );
    $year           = $date->format( 'Y' );

    // Return the season based on whether its date has passed $date.
    foreach ( $seasons as $season => $start_date ) {

        $start_date = new \DateTimeImmutable( $year . '-' . $start_date, new \DateTimeZone( $timezone ) );

        if ( $date < $start_date ) {
            return $current_season;
        }

        $current_season = $season;
    }

    return $current_season;
}
```

Usage

```
// Pass nothing to get current meteorological season in the Northern hemisphere.
echo get_season();

// Pre-PHP 8.0, though I've only tested it on 7.4.
echo get_season( 'December 18', 'Europe/London', 'northern', 'astronomical' );

// After PHP 8.0 you can use named arguments to skip the defaults.
echo get_season( 'December 18', calendar: 'astronomical' );
```

Outputs

```
winter // Current season.
autumn
autumn // If PHP 8.0, otherwise error.
```

I personally like that it lets me add calendars if I discover something unique, like for example, the beginning of Summer is always the first Thursday after April 18th in Iceland.

Answer (score 0):

you can get the index of the current season with this 1 line function

```
season(date('m'));
function season($month)
{
    return ($month + 1) === 13 ? 0 : ceil(($month + 1) / 3) - 1;
}
```