# Check season of year in php

Tags: php, html, date, datetime

I want to print a different image every season of the year. Based on a date from my database. I want to print it in php/html5.

Found some things on the internet but none of them worked with my database date.

Comment: What format does your database date have?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: How to check the season of the year and set a class accordingly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40893960/php-how-to-check-the-season-of-the-year-and-set-a-class-accordingly)

Comment: @LuisfelipeDejesusMunoz yyyy-mm-dd

Comment: Check the link from the duplicated

Comment: @LuisfelipeDejesusMunoz I got that one working, but not with my database time. How do I set the variable with the date from the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just need to format the values o match yours

```php
$someDay = "2018-12-01";

$spring = (new DateTime('March 20'))->format("Y-m-d");
$summer = (new DateTime('June 20'))->format("Y-m-d");
$fall = (new DateTime('September 22'))->format("Y-m-d");
$winter = (new DateTime('December 21'))->format("Y-m-d");

switch(true) {
    case $someDay >= $spring && $someDay < $summer:
        echo 'It\'s Spring!';
        break;

    case $someDay >= $summer && $someDay < $fall:
        echo 'It\'s Summer!';
        break;

    case $someDay >= $fall && $someDay < $winter:
        echo 'It\'s Fall!';
        break;

    default:
        echo 'It must be Winter!';
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZBBa4MwGIbv/opvUho9BDSnMdvuIoMNdupgDHaJ9nPKjIYkImPst7touw6qgeaQQ77veV7yylIOm3tp75VuBab8C7bgsyi@pTGjUewnnrfSUlXNhx0EDfaQcoMvlcCAPHOVl8AiEoZ0V7RKcBP4b1TQgx8mFuuEQDXHnroG3VTB63rO7FEaFJnVMeYA@6oxS3Ep5icyXiY93VcmLwOjOgzh2wN7cq4RzpXstvBXwnr9/7yB0x/vJmY8mJctkEfzTjTsJ@KGJOdpppB/2kBHwrGvi4SxD4d/2r/ePzV7YT@Wtux/sPsu@wEL3tVmDoLotIEM4XUyj/zPMPwC)

Answer (score 0):

Based on year of defined date and some leap year logic

```
$current_date = new DateTimeImmutable();
# $current_date = $current_date->setDate(2023,3,1); // test
$seasons = [
  (object) ['name' => 'winter', 'date' => $current_date->setDate($current_date->format('Y'),1,1)],
  (object) ['name' => 'spring', 'date' => $current_date->setDate($current_date->format('Y'),2,($current_date->format('Y') % 4 === 0) ? 19 : 20)],
  (object) ['name' => 'summer', 'date' => $current_date->setDate($current_date->format('Y'),5,($current_date->format('Y') % 4 === 0) ? 20 : 21)],
  (object) ['name' => 'autumn', 'date' => $current_date->setDate($current_date->format('Y'),8,($current_date->format('Y') % 4 === 0) ? 22 : 23)],
  (object) ['name' => 'winter', 'date' => $current_date->setDate($current_date->format('Y'),11,($current_date->format('Y') % 4 === 0) ? 20 : 21)]
];
$season = array_slice(array_filter($seasons, fn($season) => $season->date <= $current_date),-1)[0]->name;

echo $season;
```

Answer (score 0):

If your seasons are variable, and stored in the database, you can fix your problem by simply

1. Splitting the season that intersects newyear
2. Set all yearstamps to 2000
3. Do a `a < b < c` check

Splitting the season elïminates your problem straightaway

- Here's a [.NET implementation](https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer.SeasonChecker/blob/master/MintPlayer.SeasonChecker/SeasonChecker.cs#L83)
- Here's a [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pieterjandc/L3prwqmh/1/)