# Symfony Twig - want to modify the background depending on date

Tags: symfony, twig

I'm looking to change my background according to the season on a weather app.

```
{% set season = data.date | date('d-m')  %}
    {% if (season >= '21-09') and (season < '21-12') %}
        <style>
        .card-weather .card-body:first-child 
        {
            background: url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/01/09/20/22/tree-3072431_1280.jpg) no-repeat center;
        }
        </style>

    {% elseif (season >= '21-12') and (season < '21-03') %}
        <style>
        .card-weather .card-body:first-child 
        {
            background: url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2019/01/20/11/32/eiskristalle-3943558_1280.jpg) no-repeat center;
        }
        </style>
    {% elseif (season >= '21-03') and (season <= '21-06') %}
        <style>
        .card-weather .card-body:first-child 
        {
        background: url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/04/12/16/22/oilseed-rape-2224941_1280.jpg) no-repeat center;
        }
        </style>
    {% elseif (season >= '22-06') and (season <= '21-09') %}
        <style>
        .card-weather .card-body:first-child 
        {
            background: url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2019/06/27/03/42/beach-4301479_1280.jpg) no-repeat center;
        }
        </style>

    {% endif %}
```

I'm going to look for my date comes my data in my controller.
I don't see my mistake.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow. This is an English-language site. Is the text in the title an error message you get, or just something you forgot to translate?

Comment: *"I'm going to look for my date comes my data in my controller"* is not understandable. Do you mean you are trying to look for the date in the controller?

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to compare dates in `twig` I'd advise using the unix format but you'd better be off with writing a custom twig filter/function to determine which season it is.

```html
{% set background = '' %}

{% set today = 'NOW'|date('U') %}
{% set spring = 'March 20'|date('U') %}
{% set summer = 'June 20'|date('U') %}
{% set fall = 'September 22'|date('U') %}
{% set winter = 'December 21'|date('U') %}

{% if today >= spring and today < summer %}
    {% set background = 'spring.png' %}
{% elseif today >= summer and today < fall %}
    {% set background = 'summer.png' %}
{% elseif today >= fall and today < winter %}
    {% set background = 'fall.png' %}
{% else %}
    {% set background = 'winter.png' %}
{% endif %}

<style>
    .card-weather .card-body:first-child {
        background: url('{{ background }}');
    }
</style>
```

[demo](https://twigfiddle.com/s89ryg) - [reference dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50140498/check-season-of-year-in-php)

Comment: It's the first time I've asked a question about stackoverflow and it's really nice to have answered it.
It works very well
Thank you very much